# How to Mapping Deserialize XML document using c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-serialization

i am new to c # programming and i m stuck in how ot Deserialize this XML document, i have seen this tutorial [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) and it was helpful but as you can see my XML contains more informations and he is more complex :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Classrooms>
    <Classroom name="ClassroomA">
        <Students name = "John"/>
        <Students name = "Bryan"/>
        <Students name = "Eva"/>
    </Classroom>
    <Classroom name="ClassroomB">
        <Students name = "Harry"/>
        <Students name = "Emma"/>
        <Students name = "Joe"/>
    </Classroom>
    <Classroom name="ClassroomC">
        <Students name = "Lionnel"/>
        <Students name = "Rio"/>
        <Students name = "Eva"/>
    </Classroom>
</Classrooms>
```

My main goal is to create a Map of classrooms from my XML file :

example : Dictionnary<string,List> classrooms ,

Key 1 : classroomA, Values : John,Bryan,Eva

Key 2 : classroomB, Values : Harry,Emma,Joe

Key 3 : classroomC, Values : Lionnel,Rio,Eva

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication178
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Classrooms));
            Classrooms classrooms = (Classrooms)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            //using xml linq
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = doc.Descendants("Classroom")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Elements("Students").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("name")).ToList());
        }
    }
    public class Classrooms
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public List<Classroom> Classroom { get; set; }
    }
    public class Classroom
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement()]
        public List<Students> Students { get; set; }

    }
    public class Students
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it work as i except, big Thanks bro :)